# What is the mechanism happening in defining twisted module?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

What is the twisted module ?

What is the mechanism happening here ?

From [The Stack project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JL), the definition is as follows:

Let $S=\bigoplus_{d \geq 0} S_d$ be a graded ring ($S_d \cdot S_e \subset S_{d+e}$) over an abelian group and $M=\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} M_n$ be a $S$-module ($S_d \cdot M_e \subset M_{d+e}$).

For $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define the graded $S$-module $M(n)$ such that $$M(n)_d:=M_{n+d}.$$ This $M(n)$ is the twisted module of $M$ by a twist $n$. This is the definition in the above link.

But I want to understand the mechanism here.

Clearly, $M(n)$ is a graded module, so we can express $M(n)$ as a decomposition. Assume for some fixed $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have $$M=M_{n_0} \oplus M_{n_0+1}\oplus\cdots,$$ and so we have $$M(n)=M_{n_0+n} \oplus M_{n_0+1+n} \oplus \cdots.$$
So basically we are changing(or probably reshuffling) the submodules of $M$ when we are defining the twist.

I welcome some comments and explanation which I am missing.

I would love one example

Thanks

Comment: You're just changing the indices. Note that $M(n)$ will have some negative indices when $n$ is positive, even if $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$-graded module. Also, it can also be obtained by taking $M(n) = S(n) \otimes M$

Comment: @Daniel, I have a confusion here. I understand that the decomposition will change. But does it mean that every (at least one) entry in the decomposition of $M(n)$ will have changes by new module which was not in the previous decomposition of $M$ ?